# What could prevent Recovery Mode from activating?

Tags: macos

I'm trying to access [Recovery Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314) on a 13-inch mid-2009 MacBook Pro running 10.8. Although I believe that I'm performing the right steps, the computer boots normally instead of entering recovery mode. I'm able to use the machine normally aside from being unable to enter Recovery Mode.

While the computer is shut down completely, I hold the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys, press the power button, and release the held keys once the Apple logo appears. Then my normal desktop appears, as if I hadn't held the keys at all.

What could prevent Recovery Mode from activating?

Comment: I started off wanting to access Recovery Mode so that I could copy the startup disk to an external drive in preparation for swapping drives. I'm pretty sure I can find another way to do that, but now I'm curious!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the main requirement for Recovery Mode is a recovery partition. Typically the recovery partition is created when installing Mac OSX, but in some cases may not be. If the recover partition was not created, Recovery Mode cannot be accessed.

Check whether you have a recovery partition by executing `diskutil list` from the Terminal and searching for an entry for "Apple_Boot Recovery HD" (thanks to an [Apple SE answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42599/how-do-i-know-if-i-have-the-lion-recovery-partition-set-up) for the steps).

If you lack a recovery partition, you can create one using [Recovery Partition Creator](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2014/07/recovery-partition-creator-3-8/) and an OSX installer. The installer is placed in the Applications directory after downloading the update from the App Store (and is removed upon installing the update). You can redownload an installer from the App Store if you originally obtained it there via the Purchases tab.

In my case, installing the latest OSX (El Capitan) created the recovery partition with no additional work from me.